# Getting contact details from user in a listView form

Tags: android, forms, contacts, vcf-vcard

I am developing a .vc application. I need to provide a form to the user to fill up fields such as name, number, title, email, website etc. in a listView layout. How i can do it?

Appreciate your helps.Thx

Comment: Please google it. You'll find lots of examples related to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create simple form using textview and edittexts in Linear Layout with vertical orientation and use list view to display items stored.

Go through these examples - http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/06/01/sqlite-database-example/ to store data and http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ to display data in listview.